# Batch extract images from *.mts every 30 seconds?

Tags: windows, command-line, video, batch

Forgive me as I am just getting started with ffmpeg. I have a folder of *.mts videos (titles are sort of wonky, lots of spaces and characters and numbers---not sure if this is affecting it) and I need to extract images every 30 seconds for all of the videos in a folder.

I have good scripts for extracting it one by one, such as

ffmpeg -i "*.mts" -start_number 0 -vf fps=1/30 "B 00-%02d-30.000.png"

However, I need to create a batch file to do it for all .mts files in a specified folder.

Any chance someone can explain to me how to write it (assuming batch file is in same location as photos)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `for` command:

```
for /f "delims=|" %%f in ('dir /b *.mts') do (ffmpeg -i "%%f" -start_number 0 -vf fps=1/30 "B 00-%02d-30.000.png")
```

I haven't checked the syntax of your ffmpeg command, but this should work from a batch file when it is run with the working directory being the path of your folder. Otherwise you could change `dir /b *.mts` to something like `dir /b C:\FolderWithFiles\*.mts` or use the `%~dp0` to have it use the path where your batch file lives.

**EDIT:** Also, please note that if you're trying to test the command outside of a batch file and directly from the command prompt, you'll need to change the `%%f`'s to be `%f`.